# How to edit python file on Google Cloud Shell

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have created the basic "Hello World" web app and deployed it. So I have the URL with my project name included in it. I wanted to create a couple of changes to the source code, but when I try refreshing it shows no changes. How do I make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If you deployed the app

`gcloud app update`

## If it's testing in Cloud Shell

I missed where you stated the app was deployed and wrote the answer below. I'll leave it for future readers or in case it might help.

> To stop the local server from the command line, you press the
>   following:
>
> Mac OS X or Linux: Control-C Windows: Control-Break

Then restart again with

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

This assumes you're completing the App Engine hello world tutorial.

Still not working? Maybe you have multiple processes running or something else is wrong. Let's try killing all of the web server processes and restarting.

`ps aux | grep dev_appserver.py`

Look at the process number.

`kill PROCESS_NUM_HERE`

If you see multiple processes after running `ps aux...` then you should kill all of them.

Then restart

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Comment: Well I tried that and it said "Nothing to update". I would like to edit my code and re-deploy it.